# Generic list and for-each loop

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

I am using a  generic class `TestThrows< T >` with a containing function that returns a generic list . My problem is i am unable to compile this program and it is throwing following error :

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Throwable**

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        TestThrows testThrows = new TestThrows();

        // compile error on the next line
        for ( Throwable t : testThrows.getExceptions() )
        {
            t.toString();
        }
    }

    static class TestThrows< T >
    {
        public List< Throwable > getExceptions()
        {
            List< Throwable > exceptions = new ArrayList< Throwable >();
            return exceptions;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why is this error as i am using generic list ?

Comment: You use a raw Type of TestThrows. That messes up the generics of your method call.

Answer (score 2):

You declared a generic type parameter `T` for `TestThrows`, which you never use.

That makes the type of `TestThrows testThrows = new TestThrows()` a raw type,
which causes the return type of `getExceptions()` to also be a raw `List` instead of `List<Throwable>, so iterating over`testThrows.getExceptions()`returns`Object`references instead of`Throwable` references, and your loop doesn't pass compilation.

Just change

```
static class TestThrows< T >
{
    public List< Throwable > getExceptions()
    {
        List< Throwable > exceptions = new ArrayList< Throwable >();
        return exceptions;
    }
}
```

to

```
static class TestThrows
{
    public List< Throwable > getExceptions()
    {
        List< Throwable > exceptions = new ArrayList< Throwable >();
        return exceptions;
    }
}
```

since you are not using `T` anyway.

If you do need `T`, you should change

```
TestThrows testThrows = new TestThrows();
```

to

```
TestThrows<SomeType> testThrows = new TestThrows<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason is because you are using raw types... do instead

```
TestThrows<Throwable> testThrows = new TestThrows<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix is very simple. Instead of:

```
 TestThrows testThrows = new TestThrows();
```

use:

```
TestThrows<Throwable> testThrows = new TestThrows<Throwable>();
```